# Rotate JButton's text

Tags: java, swing, rotation, jbutton

I want my `JButton` to rotate its text (not the whole button) a bit when it's hovered. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to do 2 things:

- Build a custom paint method that displays the desired effect.
- Add a mouse motion listener to the button to detect that the effect should be activated.

Good luck, I hope this helps!

Comment: You might also add a FocusListener for us users who are not 'mouse junkies'. ;)

Answer (score 2):

What does "rotate the text a bit" mean? What is the purpose of this. As you rotate text the top and bottom will be clipped as you reach the edges of the button.

I think the basic code would be something like:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if (mouseOver)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.rotate(...);
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        g2d.rotate(...);
    }
    else
        super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Instead of rotating maybe a better solution is to shift the text up/down a couple of pixels, then you don't have to worry about truncation. The basic code should be the same but you would use the translate(...) method.